# tango to Evora phrase

Tags: meaning, phrases

There is a song by Loreena McKennitt "Tango to Evora". I know that the author meant a portugal city of Evora, but the question is: what could "tango to Evora" mean?

Comment: The question lacks details, but it's still interesting. It might have helped if you mentioned that the song is an instrumental, because that would obviate the need to examine lyrics. In fact *Tango to Evora* could have many meanings, and thus the question is ultimately unanswerable. When we perform an act *to* someone or something, it often means we do it to honor them.

Comment: On the other hand, it is not impossible for *to Evora* to mean a destination. If I start from somewhere else, I can get to Evora by tangoing (dancing the tango) to that city. Ultimately, the question is unanswerable. Even if the author had one meaning in mind, the title can be interpreted differently to that.

Comment: Thank you, Alan. The song was used in a Canadian documentary about European witch hunt and it is possible that it meant to honor the victims of the city of Evora

Comment: My hunch is *Tango dedicated to Evora*, possibly a girl named *Evora*, not the city. Two videos I saw have nothing to do with Évora.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition *to* has many meanings and is licensed in different ways by different words:

- *towards*, with *bring*, *take*, or *go*

  > Evora is such a happy place that I dance in anticipation of my arrival. In fact, along my way I **"Tango to Evora"**.
- *for*, *in honor of*, with *dedicate*

  > I love Evora so much, that I will dedicate my **"Tango to Evora"**.
- *resonate with*, *along with*

  > Evora is such a lively city, with a beat all its own. When I'm there, I **"Tango to Evora"**.

As long as I'm guessing, let me posit that Evora is such a wonderful place that it has an eponymous verb meaning *to become ecstatic*. (Or perhaps it's such a terrible place that the verb means *to become depressed*.) In either case, we can use an infinitive of purpose.

> When I feel a wave of emotion, I **"Tango** [in order] **to Evora"**.

Comment: How about the Jewish L'Chaim ("to life")? (which can also be translated "for life"!). See http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2987145/jewish/Why-Do-Jews-Toast-LChaimTo-Life.htm

Comment: @rhetorician I can't see how to fit the tango in with the chabadniks. The hora, perhaps.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of dance so much as the preposition "to," and how it's used to say, in effect, "here's to you" or "here's to _______________ (fill in the blank). The expression has a dedicatory nature, almost like the phrase "I dedicate this (salute) to you." A distant memory: Didn't Gordon Lightfoot have an album called "Salute"? I'll have to look that one up. Don